# How to restrict angular2-date-picker future date selection

Tags: angular, validation, date, datepicker

I don't want allow to a user select future date in angular2-date-picker,How can i achieve such behavior? My code is the following.

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
   <div>
     <label>From
        <angular2-date-picker
          [(ngModel)]="fromDate"
          [settings]="settings"
          (click)="customizeFromDatePicker()"
        ></angular2-date-picker
     ></label>
   </div>
    <div>
      <label
        >To
        <angular2-date-picker
          [(ngModel)]="toDate"
          [settings]="settings"
          (click)="customizeToDatePicker()"
        ></angular2-date-picker
      ></label>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: angular2-date-picker has limitation please check below answer that will solve your problem

Comment: if you think that provided solution solved your problem then you can accept the answer so that others will get benefit out of it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a limitation in angular2 picker which you are using.

Here is another best Angular 2 datepicker which fits in your requirement.

[Here is link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datepicker)

Here are steps to implement.

**Step 1**: Install Library: `npm install angular2-datepicker`

**Step 2**: Import Module in AppModule :

```
import {MyDatePickerModule} from 'mydatepicker';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    MyDatePickerModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

**Step 3**: app.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="datepickerForm" novalidate>
    <my-date-picker name="mydate" 
            [options]="myDatePickerOptions"
            formControlName="startDate"
            (dateChanged)="onDateChanged($event)">
      </my-date-picker>
  <!-- other controls are here... -->
  <button (click)="showSelectedDate()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Step 4**: app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  datepickerForm: FormGroup;
  selectedDate: any;
  myDatePickerOptions: any;

  constructor(public _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.datepickerForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      'startDate': [null, Validators.required]
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myDatePickerOptions = {
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
      disableUntil : {year: 2016, month: 7, day: 22},
      disableSince :  {year: 2019, month: 4, day: 22}
    }
  }

  showSelectedDate() {
    let date: any = this.datepickerForm.controls['startDate'].value;
    this.selectedDate = date.formatted;
    console.log(this.selectedDate);
  }

  onDateChanged(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

**[Here working solution on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/datepicker-angular2-1hassq?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property `disableSince`.

Before doing so, you might want to get future date first:

```
get tomorrowDate(): Date {
   const todayDate = new Date();
   const tomorrowDate = new Date(todayDate.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

   return tomorrowDate;
}
```

After that, you can insert the `disableSince` property to make it work:

```
this.myDatePickerOptions = {
   dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
   disableSince: { year: this.tomorrowDate.getFullYear(), month: this.tomorrowDate.getMonth() + 1, day: this.tomorrowDate.getDate() }
}
```

[**Working Stackblitz Example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2-datepicker)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is for my-date-picker, Actually Im looking to do the same in  angular2-date-picker, Any way Thanks  for your help.